# Problem with universal cloth size (S,M,L) regex

Tags: regex

Having issue with my regex. My goal is detect cloth size and cut other data.

Here is some examples of size:

```
2XS
M
XXL Long
XL Short
```

Here is my regex

```
^(\d*[SMLX]+)\s*.*#
```

This regex works for most cases, but it works wrong, if my size contain chars out from the range of allowed.

For `XXL` Long or `2XL` it returns correct data (`XXL` and `2XL`), but if my size looks like `2AXL`, it returns `2XL`, but in this case it must return an empty result, because "A" char is out of allowed chars range.

Comment: The `#` at the end is not in the example data. Note that it is a broad match and will also match MMXXMM. If you remove the `#` at the end, 2AXL will not match. See https://regex101.com/r/L2Wx7p/1 Can you give an example where you get that match?

Comment: What's the language/tool? When asking question about regex, set the tag of the tool or language you're using.

Comment: May be you need just alternation? `\d*(XL|XXL|M|XS)\b`. Add other sizes as you need.

Comment: Your regex [does not match `2AXL`](https://regex101.com/r/HNhQT9/1)

Comment: @Thefourthbird, sorry, this is PHP example and `#` is a part of `preg_match('#REGEX#')` example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex `[SMLX]` matches `S`, `M`, `L` **or** `X`.

What you describe can be achieved with [the following regex](https://regex101.com/r/lm4fOw/3):

```
^(\d*(?:M|X{0,2}[SL]))(?:$|\s+.*$)
```

Which matches either plain `M`, or optional `X`s that are followed by <`S` or `L`> preceded.

I've also modified the suffix of your regex, to match strings that has no suffix after the size and prevent from `\s` matching a newline operator - which results in matching multi-lined strings.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution filtering as expected

Comment: Your regex will match `XS`. Is there such size?

Comment: @JohnyL Yes, according to the OP's first example

Comment: Oops! Missed that)) 